# ELAN touchpad (04F3:0401) enable double finger scrolling

Tags: debian, touchpad, scrolling, synaptic, asus

I'm having trouble enabling the two finger scrolling on my new Asus X540L.

```
sugarman@sugarman:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

sugarman@sugarman:~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep ELAN
N: Name="ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401"
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-9/i2c-ELAN1000:00/0018:04F3:0401.0001/input/input6

sugarman@sugarman:~$ uname -a
Linux sugarman 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have an ELAN touchpad and I use Debian. I followed instructions from this page: https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad.

I copied the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf --> to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf

I modified the file to match my needs, here it is:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
        Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
        Option          "AccelFactor"           "0.075"
        Option          "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"     # multitouch
        Option          "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "1"     # multitouch
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

According to this page: http://who-t.blogspot.ca/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html, the problem is caused because the device is loaded twice, once with a /dev/input/eventX path and another time with the /dev/input/mouseX path.

After reboot these new configurations still cause error with the driver "ic2_hid":

```
sugarman@sugarman:~$ sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | grep hid
Sep 18 10:27:28 sugarman kernel: [    0.773763] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Sep 18 10:27:28 sugarman kernel: [    7.930955] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1000:00: error in i2c_hid_init_report size:653 / ret_size:7
Sep 18 10:27:28 sugarman kernel: [    7.935696] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1000:00: error in i2c_hid_init_report size:131 / ret_size:7
Sep 18 10:27:28 sugarman kernel: [    7.935941] hid-generic 0018:04F3:0401.0001: input,hidraw0:  HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401] on
```

And I still get these errors even though the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package is installed (synaptics driver).

```
sugarman@sugarman:~$ synclient 
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
sugarman@sugarman:~$ syndaemon 
Unable to find a synaptics device.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Debian Wiki, it seems that you are using the libinput driver instead of the synaptics one, and this is why the `synclient` command fails.
As advised by Debian Wiki:

> You can make the synaptics driver take precedence over libinput by
>   copying /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf into
>   /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, so as to make it take precendence over the
>   libinput configuration file found at
>   /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf.

Make the copy, modify the copied file as you wish but be sure to maintain the same name (i.e `50-synaptics.conf`) in the new directory, since this number is a kind of priority number. 
To find the correct conf file in your system run

```
find / -name '*.conf' |grep synaptics
```

For example in my pc the file is named `70-synaptics.conf` and not 50.

Moreover to be sure that libinput driver is out of the game i use to do the following:
I locate the libinput conf file : `find / -name '*.conf' |grep libinput`
I edit this `90-libinput.conf` file (your libinput.conf can have a different number) abd i comment out the part that refers to touchpad to be sure that libinput will not handle touchpad:

```
#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
#        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#        Driver "libinput"
#EndSection
```

Once the libinput is out of the game and synaptics driver is used, you must be able to use synclient.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy any config files, just put this to autostart of your desktop environment: `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1`